# How do I connect multiple computer in one xampp database locally?

Tags: vb.net, xampp

I am using vb.net 2013 and the application is ready for deployment but our adviser asked us if we can connect our application in multiple computers by just using one database(xampp).

How do I make this possible?

Comment: Could you provide more details on the function you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

1. Once you did an application which is connected to a database just simply copy this app into any other pc and start it but make sure the XAMPP is running on only 1 pc
   (and be sure the server where the XAMPP is running the firewall is not blocking the database connection).
2. You can connect to a database from wherever you want if you wrote your app like that.